# How do you set the Adam optimizer learning rate in tensorflow.js?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js

For tensorflow.js, how do you set the learning rate for the Adam optimizer in node.js?  I get an error:

> model.optimizer.setLearningRate is not a function

```
const optimizer = tf.train.adam(0.001)
model.compile({
    loss: 'sparseCategoricalCrossentropy',
    optimizer,
    shuffle: true,
    metrics: ['accuracy']
});

await model.fit(trainValues, trainLabels, {
    epochs: 50,
    validationData: [testValues, testLabels],
    callbacks: {
        onEpochBegin: async (epoch) => {
            const newRate = getNewRate();
            model.optimizer.setLearningRate(newRate);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you provided?

Comment: This is the error I get: model.optimizer.setLearningRate is not a function

Comment: @Andrew That's because this function only exists for `sgd`. You have to use the unofficial API to change the learningRate for other optimizers. I put it into my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call [`model.compile`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.LayersModel.compile), you can pass an instance of [`tf.train.Optimizer`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#class:train.Optimizer) instead of passing a string. These instances are created via the [`tf.train.*`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#Training-Optimizers) factories and you can pass the learning rate as first argument.

**Code Sample**

```js
model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.000001), // custom learning rate
    /* ... */
});
```

**Changing the Learning Rate during training**

Currently, only the `sgd` optimizers has a [`setLearningRate`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/28fd4040a0714593eb0fcea383307f94cb0e5237/src/optimizers/sgd_optimizer.ts#L61) method implemented, meaning the following code only works for optimizer instances created via [`tf.train.sgd`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#train.sgd):

```js
const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(0.001);
optimizer.setLearningRate(0.000001);
```

**Using non-official API**

The optimizer instances are having a `protected` attribute [`learningRate`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/28fd4040a0714593eb0fcea383307f94cb0e5237/src/optimizers/adam_optimizer.ts#L37), which you can change. The attribute is not public but, as this is JavaScript, you can simply change the value by setting `learningRate` on the object like this:

```js
const optimizer = tf.train.adam();
optimizer.learningRate = 0.000001;
// or via your model:
model.optimizer.learningRate = 0.000001;
```

Keep in mind, you are using a non-official part of the API, which might break anytime.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a model, one can set the learning rate when passing the `optimizer` to `model.compile`

```
const myOptimizer = tf.train.sgd(myLearningRate) 
model.compile({optimizer: myOptimizer, loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
```

The learning rate can be changed during training by using `setLearningRate`

```
model.fit(xs, ys, {
  epochs: 800, 
  callbacks: {
    onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {

      if (epoch == 300){
        model.optimizer.setLearningRate(0.14)  
    }

      if (epoch == 400){
        model.optimizer.setLearningRate(0.02)   
      }
    }
  } 
})
```